# Umbraco 7 fields show locally, but not at remote server?

Tags: umbraco7

Does anyone know about this problem: Any new fields I add work fine in the local back office, but when I use Webmatrix to publish to the server (discountASP.net) fields don't show up. I did a view source in the browser and they're just not there!

For example, @Umbraco.Field("comments")

Thanks!
Daniel

Answer (score 1):

If you add new field, they are only added in the database.  That means you would need to update the database on the production website.  Webmatrix doesn't do this for you (by default).

There are a few ways to handle this scenario:

- copy your database to the production server (i would advice against this, because you might overwrite content and media changes on the production server)
- create the fields manually on the production server (easy solution)
- use a commercial package like courrier (personally i believe it's a good solution, only if you have a content staging workflow)
- use a free package like usync (http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/usync)